# how to extract more touch points from UIResponder?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiresponder

When I touch a UIView with the base of my finger tip, and get the touch point using touches anyObject, I get a single touch point, even though the base of my finger tip has an area that touches a lot many points. Is there a way to get all those points? If there is no such way, how are simple paint apps implemented in ios?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the only point / touch. Each touch is related to a single finger. This is controlled by iOS.

'Simple' drawing / painting apps use the path traced by the touch points together with the current line drawing width and texture to create lines or bezier paths.

If you're trying to create a drawing app with some form of pressure sensitivity then you'd need to integrate with a 3rd party stylus ([like this one](http://hex3.co/products/jaja))